# Time series - aggregate by a custom period of time

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

New to zoo/xts. I'm trying to go from monthly values to quarterly aggregates, defined as the sum of monthly values over a 3-month period *ending on the last available month*.

Reproducible example:

```r
library(xts)
months <- as.yearmon(c(paste0("2021-", 11:12),
                       paste0("2022-", 1:10)))
values <- c(23, 21, 45, 63, 12, 45,
            23, 91, 28, 17, 27, 28)

ts <- as.xts(values,
       order.by = months,
       dateFormat="yearmon")
ts
#>          [,1]
#> Nov 2021   23
#> Dec 2021   21
#> Jan 2022   45
#> Feb 2022   63
#> Mar 2022   12
#> Apr 2022   45
#> May 2022   23
#> Jun 2022   91
#> Jul 2022   28
#> Aug 2022   17
#> Sep 2022   27
#> Oct 2022   28
```

Intended output:

```
|          | [,1] |
| -------- | ---- |
| Jan 2022 | 89   |
| Apr 2022 | 120  |
| Jul 2022 | 142  |
| Oct 2022 | 72   |
```

I can't get this to work because the `apply.quarterly` function uses calendar quarters, rather than generic 3-month periods:

```r
apply.quarterly(ts, sum)
#>          [,1]
#> Dec 2021   44
#> Mar 2022  120
#> Jun 2022  159
#> Sep 2022   72
#> Oct 2022   28
```

And `period.apply` doesn't accept custom periods:

```r
period.apply(ts, endpoints(ts, on = "3 months"), sum)
#> Error in match.arg(on, c("years", "quarters", "months", "weeks", "days", : 'arg' should be one of "years", "quarters", "months", "weeks", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds", "milliseconds", "microseconds", "ms", "us"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your approach (i.e. `period.apply` and `endpoints`) with the `k`-argument:

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)

period.apply(ts, endpoints(ts, "months", k = 3), sum)
```

Output:

```
         [,1]
Jan 2022   89
Apr 2022  120
Jul 2022  142
Oct 2022   72
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rollaply` from zoo package:

```
> na.omit(rollapply(ts_data, width=3, by=3, FUN = sum))
          [,1]
ene. 2022   89
abr. 2022  120
jul. 2022  142
oct. 2022   72
```

Note that in your expected output you showed the sum of values not the mean values, so if you want get mean instead, just set `FUN=mean`:

```
> na.omit(rollapply(ts_data, width=3, by=3, FUN = mean))
              [,1]
ene. 2022 29.66667
abr. 2022 40.00000
jul. 2022 47.33333
oct. 2022 24.00000
```